# Como colocar links em palavras automaticamente com javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, link

Se na pagina conter as palavras "contato", "ajuda" e outras.. transformar-las em um link:

```
<a href='http://meusite.com/pagina1.html'>contato</a>

<a href='http://meusite.com/pagina2.html'>ajuda</a>
```

**Exemplo:**

Você talvez precise de [ajuda](http://meusite.com/pagina1.html), caso tenha duvidas entre em [contato](http://meusite.com/pagina2.html) conosco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta solução usa `replace` com Expressão Regular para substituir as ocorrências. Porém é necessário que o texto a ser analisado esteja dentro de alguma tag.

**Exemplo:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var links = {
      "contato aqui": "linkcontatoaqui.html",
      "abaixo-assinado": "linkaabaixoassinado.html",
      "ajuda": "linkajuda.html",
      "linha": "linklinha.html"
   }
   
   var bodi = document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(script)");
   for(var x=0; x<bodi.length; x++){
      var html = bodi[x].innerHTML;
      for(var i in links){
         var re = new RegExp("\\b(?![^<]*?>)("+i+")(?!>)", "gi");
         html = html.replace(re, ' <a href="'+links[i]+'">$1</a>');
      }
      bodi[x].innerHTML = html;
   }
});
```

```html
Contato ← este não é alterado porque não está dentro de uma tag
<div class="ajuda">
<div data-url="http://ajuda.com">ajuda</div>
   <br>
   abaixo-assinado galinha ou linha
   <br>
   Você talvez precise de ajuda, caso tenha duvidas entre em Contato conosco
   <p>Você talvez precise de Ajuda caso tenha duvidas entre em contato.</p>
</div>
<p>Você talvez precise de Ajuda caso tenha duvidas entre em contato aqui ajuda.</p>
```

A expressão `"\\b(?![^<]*?>)("+i+")(?!>)"` irá buscar no HTML dos elementos cada nome dos itens do objeto `links` e fazer o `replace` pelo grupo `$1` e aplicando o seu respectivo valor na tag `<a>`.

Pelo padrão da expressão regular, só serão substituídas as palavras que não estiverem dentro dos limitadores de tags `<>` (atributos, propriedades etc.). O `gi` são as opções da expressão. O `g` irá capturar todas as ocorrências, e o `i` irá ignorar o *case sensitive* (veja que no exemplo tanto a palavra "ajuda" quanto "Ajuda" foram substituídas).

Este seletor `document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(script)");` irá selecionar todos os elementos que estiver no `body` (exceto textos fora de tags, conforme dito no início desta resposta) e o `:not(script)` irá impedir que seja selecionado conteúdo de scripts, que não interessa neste caso.

No objeto `links` você pode criar uma lista de palavras, seguido do link que deseja para cada uma:

```
var links = {
   "contato": "linkcontato.html",
   "ajuda": "linkajuda.html" ← link da palavra
}     ↑
  palavra a ser
   substituída
```

### Edit

Para pular tags que não possuem innerHTML pode-se incluir o conteúdo do primeiro `for` em um `if` que faz essa verificação:

```
for(var x=0; x<bodi.length; x++){
   if(bodi[x].innerHTML.length){ // ← ignora tags sem innerHTML
      var html = bodi[x].innerHTML;
      for(var i in links){
         var re = new RegExp("\\b(?![^<]*?>)("+i+")(?!>)", "gi");
         html = html.replace(re, ' <a href="'+links[i]+'">$1</a>');
      }
      bodi[x].innerHTML = html;
   }else{
      console.log(bodi[x]);
   }
}
```

Comment: se eu quiser que pegue somente dentro de uma `div` com uma classe especifica eu devo mudar `document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(script)");` para `getElementsByClassName("nome");`?

Comment: algumas palavras são seguidas por `&nbsp;` exemplo `&nbsp;Confirmação` como faço pra funcionar com essas palavras também?

Comment: Altere duas linhas: `var re = new RegExp("([\\s|&nbsp;]"+i+"(?:(?=[,<.\\s])))", "gi");` e `return ' <a href="'+links[i]+'">'+a.match(/[A-zÀ-ú]+/)[0]+'</a>';`

Comment: ótimo script, mas como fazer para pegar 2 palavras ou mais? por exemplo `"contato aqui": "linkcontato.html",` ou `"abaixo-assinado": "linkcontato.html"`

Comment: @MarkVaaz Código alterado e melhorado.

Comment: @JonyBoy Alterei o código da resposta, agora ficou bem melhor. Substitua pelo que estava antes. Abs!

Comment: eu tinha alterado `(/[A-zÀ-ú]+/)` para `(/[A-zÀ-ú\s-]+/)` mas como você colocou realmente está melhor, porém eu tenho uma duvida sobre essa parte: `document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(script)");` o pseudo elemento `:not()` é de css certo? eu tentei adicionar `:not(img)` e não funcionou pra mim, como faço para ignorar tanto `<script>` quanto `<img>`?

Comment: @MarkVaaz `:not()` é pseudo-classe. Funcionaria se vc fizer desta forma: `document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(script):not(img)")`

Comment: O primeiro código funcionou melhor para mim, porque esse novo está alterando palavras como por exemplo `galinha` sendo que a palavra adicionada é somente `linha`

Comment: @MarkVaaz É verdade... vou ver isso. Uma forma de ignorar tags que não tenham innerHTML (como <img>, por exemplo) sem que seja preciso colocar o :not(img), seria colocando o conteúdo do primeiro `for` dentro de um `if(/\w/.test(bodi[x].innerHTML)){`

Comment: @MarkVaaz Adicionando `\\b` na regex acho que resolveu o problema da galinha (atualizei na resposta o exemplo).

Comment: Sim `\\b` resolveu o problema

Comment: @MarkVaaz Só uma correção no if que falei acima, o melhor seria: `if(bodi[x].innerHTML.length){`... não precisa usar `.test`. Vou incluir isso na resposta como sugestão.

Comment: @sam eu resolvi alterar o estilo do link `style='color:#232323'` e percebi que os links ja presentes no site também estão sendo substituídos e isso arruinaria por exemplo um botão feito a partir de um link  como: `<a href='#' style='background-color:#000; padding:10px;'>Botão</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Imaginando que este texto esteja dentro de um elemento HTML, exemplo:

```
<div class="texto">Você talvez precise de ajuda, caso tenha duvidas entre em contato conosco</div>
```

Você pode usar esta função:

```js
function substitiuirPalavraPorLink (palavras) {
  var textos = document.getElementsByClassName('texto');

  if (textos) {
    for (i = 0; i < textos.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < palavras.length; j++) {
        if (textos[i].innerHTML.search(palavras[j].palavra) ) {
          textos[i].innerHTML=textos[i].innerHTML.replace( palavras[j].palavra, criarLink(palavras[j].link, palavras[j].palavra));
        }
      }
    }
  }

}

function criarLink (link, palavra) {
  return '<a href="' + link + '">' + palavra + '</a>';
}

function Substituir(){
//define quais palavras serão substituidas pelo respctivo link
var palavras = [{
    palavra: 'contato',
    link: 'http://meusite.com/pagina1.html'
  },
  {
    palavra: 'ajuda',
    link: 'http://meusite.com/pagina1.html'
  }
];
substitiuirPalavraPorLink(palavras);
}
```

```html
<div class="texto">Você talvez precise de ajuda, caso tenha duvidas entre em contato conosco</div>

<div class="texto">Caso tente entrar em contato, não peça ajuda</div>

<input type='button' onCLick="Substituir();" value="Substituir" />
```

Basicamente o que a rotina faz é encontar todas as tags com a classe Texto usando o método [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) e substituir as palavras em fornecidas em uma lista.

Comment: E se eu quiser que seja dentro do `<body>` e alterar para `document.getElementsByTagName("BODY");` tem algum problema? pode haver algum mal funcionamento na pagina?

Comment: Se você garantir que as palavras não serão propriedade de uma tag especifica, não vejo problemass

Comment: eu quero que o script execute quando a pagina carregar onde coloco `window.onload`?

Comment: eu apliquei o script na pagina e retornou alguns erros pode me ajudar? https://stackoverflowteste.blogspot.com/2018/07/teste.html